# Do I need a visa to change planes in India?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, us-citizens

I live in NYC.  In November, I am taking a vacation to the Maldives, using United miles. The route I am taking is UA from EWR to Zurich. 4 hour layover in Zurich and then flying Swiss to Delhi.  4 hour layover in Delhi, and then flying Air India to Male, Maldives.   Since I am only changing planes in Delhi, and will only be there for a few hours, I don’t see that I need a visa (US Passport only).  Can anyone please confirm?  I have a US passport.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: No, you don't need a visa to change planes in India.

Long Answer: If an airline passenger is refused entry at a transit point or destination, the airline is required to return the passenger to the point of departure *at the airline's expense* (although they may try to recover the cost from the passenger). Thus, airlines are very careful to determine what documents are required by a particular passenger's travel before allowing that passenger to board. Airlines use the IATA database [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) to reveal what documents are required.

Putting your information into Timatic through [this online portal](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b) (there other others), generates this:

> India - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Passengers transiting through Bangalore (BLR), Chennai (MAA), Delhi (DEL), Kolkata (CCU) or Mumbai (BOM) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Because you're transiting Dehli and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours, you may transit India without a visa provided you remain in the international transit area of the airport.

Comment: Thank you.   I just found this website today and am amazed at how helpful everyone is.